# Get files from Google Drive SDK using C# .NET

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm doing an application that access a google drive and get a file for my web application. I'm doing in C# .Net 4. Does anybody how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You will have better luck getting an answer if you show us an example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [C# Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) to start your project. It will guide you to set up authentication. Then, use Files.get() to retrieve metadata of the file which has downloadUrl to download content of the file. All sample code of retrieving metadata and downloading content is available in C# in the [documentation for Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get).